# How can I get a contour from a binary image, while the pixels are not connected?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have some trouble to get a connected contour of the following binary image. The Problem is that the points/pixels are not connected. Normally I would train a neural network to predict a contour, but I think it's a little overkill for this problem. Any ideas for an (opencv) algorithm which can solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: morphological operations could help, but i don't think they alone could do the trick

Comment: Dilation + median can help

Comment: perfect! that helped a lot. I filterd the image with ur algorithms and  added something like  cellular automata to enclose the holes between the pixel